# How do I trigger an event on model change in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to build a [drum machine](https://github.com/iampeterbanjo/phat-machine) in Angular2 similar to [an existing](https://github.com/iampeterbanjo/angular-drum-machine) Angular project.

The way I have structured the components is to have a SequencerComponent (parent) that emits an event (@Output) at a specified interval (BPM).

```
// sequencer.component.ts
@Output() metronome = new EventEmitter();

  onBeat(count: number) {
    if(this.isPlaying) {
      this.beat.one = count == 1;
      this.beat.two = count == 2;
      this.beat.three = count == 3;
      this.beat.four = count == 4;

      this.metronome.emit(this.beat);
    }
  }
```

PadsComponent (child) listens to this event (@Input) and should then play a sound if a PadComponent (grand-child) is set to active.

```
// pads.component.ts
export class PadsComponent {
  @Input() hit: any = {};
}

// pads.component.html
<pad [class.active]="hit.one" class="column pad"></pad>

<pad [class.active]="hit.two" class="column pad"></pad>

<pad [class.active]="hit.three" class="column pad"></pad>

<pad [class.active]="hit.four" class="column pad"></pad>
```

I can get the classes to change but obviously I want to do more than HTML attribute binding. [Working example](http://iampeterbanjo.2016.angularattack.io/)

How can I get the child and grand-child to run a function on model change? And is there a better, more idiomatic way to solve this problem?

I have tried using `ngDoCheck` but I haven't discovered how to use it in this use case.

**Update**: `hit` is being bound to the `beat` in `sequencer.component.html` like so:

```
<!-- sequencer.component.html -->
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <a class="button is-success" (click)="onPlay($event)" href="">Play</a>

    <a class="button is-danger" (click)="onStop($event)" href="">Stop</a>
  </div>
</div>

<pads [hit]="beat"></pads>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `@Input() hit: any = {};` you can have a getter and a setter for `hit` :

```
private _hit;  // define a private variable _hit

@Input()
set hit(hit:any){  
    this._hit = hit;  // set the private variable and do whatever you want after each change
    playSomeSound(hit);
}
get hit(){  
    return this._hit;
}
```

Your template code is still the same,

```
<pad [class.active]="hit.one" class="column pad"></pad>
...
```

[check this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BC2GD0B6QassDyJuHszu?p=preview) for an example.

Comment: Thanks! I'm accepting this solution because it seems more idiomatic to Angular2

Comment: `set hit(hit:any)` seems to fire only once when the component is initialised and not when the model is changed :(

Comment: @Peter It should fire every time you set `hit`. Could you include your code for setting `hit` ?

Comment: Thank you for the plunk example. I'm updating my Angular2 version to see if that helps

Comment: @Peter I don't recall any breaking changes that could effect `Input`. You problem is most likely on the way you are passing values to `hit`, it will be more clear if you could include that code in your question.

Comment: @Peter I don't like this part in your question in particular `SequencerComponent (parent) that emits an event `. Parents should not emit to children, it's the other way around.

Comment: I have included how values are being passed to hit in the question. Also you're right in that typically `events go up (from children) and data comes down (from parents)` which is why I tried to use a model (hit/beat). But then how do I keep all the components in time/sync using a a child component? Perhaps by injecting a service instead? I've been doing some research into the Rx library you used to create an Observable to see if there are some answers there

Comment: @Peter, the `Rx` library is `rxjs` it's a part of angular2. About the event, you don't need an event to sync the beats. All your components are bound to `hit` right ? then every time you change `hit`, all the components will get the change. They are not getting the change now probably because you call `onBeat()` from outside the context. Would you add that call please ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to use `ngDoCheck()` to watch for model change and emit it:

```
ngDoCheck() {

  if (this.previousModel !== this.model) {
    this.modelChange.emit(this.model);
  }

  this.previousModel = this.model;
}
```